# Google Charts - Gauge Graph animation not working

Tags: javascript, php, animation, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to create some GAUGE graphs with Google Graphs.
My goal is to load the data from a php page and have an auto refresh.
I was able to do that, but when the data is refreshed, the Gauge lines are not animated, but instead they are redrawn from new. I would like to see the cool animation like this: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/.
Actually I'm loading the data from a static file, then I'll create the data from a MySQL database (tested and worked).
Here my code:

temperature.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://URL/fetch_data3.php?type=gauge",
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;


    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
        width: 600, height: 300,
        redFrom: 35, redTo: 50,
        yellowFrom: 24, yellowTo: 35,
        greenFrom: 18, greenTo: 24,
        majorTicks : ['-10', '0', '10','20','30','40','50'], minorTicks: 10,
        animation:{
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'inAndOut',
        },
        max: 50, min: -10
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    clearChart();

}

setInterval(function() {
    drawChart();
}, 5000);

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here the fetch_data3.php

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["type"] == "gauge") {
    $sec = date('s');
if ($sec % 2 == 0) {
    $string = file_get_contents("sampleData.json");
} else {
    $string = file_get_contents("sampleData2.json");
}
echo $string;
}
?>
```

sampleData.json:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Esterno","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Soggiorno","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Stanza","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

sampleData2.json:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Esterno","f":null},{"v":10,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Soggiorno","f":null},{"v":40,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Stanza","f":null},{"v":20,"f":null}]}
      ]
}
```

The graph loads randomly sampleData2.json or sampleData.json but there is no anomation on the graph.

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Simon

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ is blank :)

Comment: Sorry, it's based on the anomation showed in the google doc: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to the [supported modifications](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#supported-modifications) for a Gauge chart,
animation only occurs when a value in the data changes

since the chart doesn't animate on `startup`,
draw the chart initially with the values set to the `min` value,
or the value at which the animation should begin

then use a *one time* `'ready'` event listener to draw the chart with the real data
this will cause the chart to animate

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();

    setInterval(function() {
      drawChart();
    }, 5000);

    function drawChart() {
      var initData = {
        "cols": [
          {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
          {"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}
        ],
        "rows": [
          {"c":[{"v":"Esterno","f":null},{"v":-10,"f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Soggiorno","f":null},{"v":-10,"f":null}]},
          {"c":[{"v":"Stanza","f":null},{"v":-10,"f":null}]}
        ]
      };

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(initData);

      var options = {
        width: 600, height: 300,
        redFrom: 35, redTo: 50,
        yellowFrom: 24, yellowTo: 35,
        greenFrom: 18, greenTo: 24,
        majorTicks : ['-10', '0', '10','20','30','40','50'], minorTicks: 10,
        animation:{
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'inAndOut'
        },
        max: 50, min: -10
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        var jsonData = {
          "cols": [
            {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
            {"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}
          ],
          "rows": [
            {"c":[{"v":"Esterno","f":null},{"v":10,"f":null}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Soggiorno","f":null},{"v":40,"f":null}]},
            {"c":[{"v":"Stanza","f":null},{"v":20,"f":null}]}
          ]
        };

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  },
  packages:['gauge']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

as mentioned, the above charts will animate...

*from the default values set -- to the real data received*

in order to get the chart to animate...

*from the previous real data -- to the new data received*

you would need to save a reference to the `chart`
instead of creating a new `chart`, everytime it is drawn

also, *highly recommend* not using `async: false` on the `$.ajax` call
use the `success` handler instead

recommend this setup, which will animate on the initial draw using default values
then animate from the previous data, to the new data on each interval

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // save reference to chart
    var chart = null;

    drawChart();

    setInterval(function() {
      drawChart();
    }, 5000);

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://URL/fetch_data3.php?type=gauge',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
          var options = {
            width: 600, height: 300,
            redFrom: 35, redTo: 50,
            yellowFrom: 24, yellowTo: 35,
            greenFrom: 18, greenTo: 24,
            majorTicks : ['-10', '0', '10','20','30','40','50'], minorTicks: 10,
            animation:{
              duration: 1000,
              easing: 'inAndOut'
            },
            max: 50, min: -10
          };

          var data;
          if (chart === null) {
            chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            // data with min values
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
              "cols": [
                {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
                {"id":"","label":"Value","pattern":"","type":"number"}
              ],
              "rows": [
                {"c":[{"v":"Esterno","f":null},{"v":-10,"f":null}]},
                {"c":[{"v":"Soggiorno","f":null},{"v":-10,"f":null}]},
                {"c":[{"v":"Stanza","f":null},{"v":-10,"f":null}]}
              ]
            });

            google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
              data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
              chart.draw(data, options);
            });
          } else {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
          }

          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  packages:['gauge']
});
```